# Are There Dangers to Writing to Ehcache in Parallel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, ehcache

In the given example, I have an inner class that defines a read-through `CacheLoaderWriter` inside of an imagined `ExampleCache` class that would abstract cache operations so that 3rd parties just think they are access a data structure (key-value pair). My question involves the `loadAll` method.

If `loadAll` is written to write to EhCache in parallel, will there be any risks of record mutation or instability? Is EhCache built to handle user-defined concurrency?

```
    class ExampleCacheLoader implements CacheLoaderWriter<String, ArrayList> {


            private HashMap<String, ArrayList> map;

            public CacheLoader() {
                map = new HashMap<>();
            }

            @Override
            public ArrayList<String> load(String s) throws Exception {

                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> personEntry = getPersonAliases(s);
                if(!map.containsKey(personEntry.getKey())){
                    map.put(personEntry.getKey(), personEntry.getValue());
                }
                return map.get(personEntry.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, ArrayList> loadAll(
                    Iterable<? extends String> keys) throws Exception {
                Map<String, ArrayList> localTempMap = new HashMap<>();
                Stream keyStream =  StreamSupport.stream(entries.spliterator(), true);
                keyStream.forEach(key -> {
                    localTempMap.putIfAbsent(
                            getterExample(key).getKey(),
                            getterExample(key).getValue());
                });

                map.putAll(localTempMap);
                return localTempMap;
            }
            .

            .

            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehcache is a library designed for concurrent access and thus handles multi threading, concurrent mutations and related problems in the best possible way.

Now your understanding of the `CacheLoaderWriter` seems problematic. You are not supposed to access the cache from a `CacheLoaderWriter` instead the `CacheLoaderWriter` will be accessed by the cache when required, that is for the `load*` methods when a mapping is requested but not found in the cache.

However your `CacheLoaderWriter` implementation *must be* thread safe as Ehcache will use it concurrently. Also in your proposed implementation you are maintaining state inside the `CacheLoaderWriter` which is redundant with what the `Cache` will do ... if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I'm relatively new to caching in Java, and my only previous experience was in C and C++ so I guess I got lucky in only having a few misunderstandings.